# Datepicker redeclare for later generated content

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to add a datepicker in the mainpage and in a modal with a form which is generated later by a ajax call.

I try it with this code, but it does not work correctly in the modal form. I have to click twice into the input file only than the datepicker will show.

Both ways I try

```
$('body').on('click','.date-picker', function() ...
```

but it won't work.

What's wrong with this code?

```
//Start DatePicker
var datePickerOptions = {
    format: 'dd.mm.yyyy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker(datePickerOptions);
});

$('body').on('click','.date-picker', function() {
   //$(this).datepicker('destroy').datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus(); 
   $('.date-picker').datepicker(datePickerOptions);       
});
//End DatePicker
```

Comment: You should initialize the datepicker inside the callback for the ajax call.

Comment: have i use it as a .on call or without .on? And why it only works after the second click at the element?